# Typoscript Calling variables inside objects

Tags: variables, constants, typoscript

I'm trying to get my head around typoscript variables, but my trial and error approach is proving fruitless as one slip and bam, the code will not work nor error out.

I'm looking to join two global vars together, and then insert them as a variable inside of a typoscript object.

This is my current code.

```
[globalString = IENV:REQUEST_URI=*url*]

page.headerData.20000 = TEXT
    page.headerData.20000.value (
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://site.site.info"/>
)

[end]
```

I want the site URL to gather the URL from the current page.

```
myvar = TEXT
myvar = getIndpEnv:TYPO3_SITE_NAME
```

Concatenate it with the current page URL, to get the entire URL

```
myvar2 = TEXT
getIndpEnv:REQUEST_URI
```

and then place it within the MetaTag to always display the current URL as the URL

```
[globalString = IENV:REQUEST_URI=*url*]

page.headerData.20000 = TEXT
    page.headerData.20000.value (
    <meta property="og:url" content="myvar3"/>
)

[end]
```

I've tried creating the var as a constant, and calling it with {$constantName} but this has not worked for me.

Sorry for such a simple request.

Comment: TypoScript is not a programming language so there are no variables in the programming sense of the word. So the main trick for programmers is to stop thinking of it like if they were programming. :-)

Comment: ...though there's "register" which might somewhat be understood as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you actually want the full URL. So you don't need to concatenate 2 values as the full URL is stored in `TYPO3_REQUEST_URL`:

```
[globalString = IENV:REQUEST_URI=*url*]
  page.headerData.20000 = TEXT
  page.headerData.20000 {
    value = <meta property="og:url" content="{getIndpEnv:TYPO3_REQUEST_URL}" />
    insertData = 1
  }
[end]
```

Comment: I got it myself eventually, but this is exactly how I fixed it. Thanks very much for the reply though!

For anyone reading. Giving the value insertData = 1 to any object makes it treat the text within brackets as if they were functions/constants/objects i.e not text.